# How to avoid SQL Injection with Update command in Npgsql?

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-injection, npgsql

I am trying to use the Npgsql PostgreSQL client to accomplish two things:

1. Avoid SQL injection, and
2. Manage data containing the single quote '

I cannot see how to do either :(

PostrgeSQL version 9.1

In the below code, dx.chronic is of type bool? and cdesc of table dx may contain single quote, as "Tom's dog". Clearly, UpdateCmd, as written, will fail when Npgsql/PostgreSQL hits the single quote.

```
string sChronic = (dx.chronic == null) ? "null" : dx.chronic.ToString(); 

string UpdateCmd = "update dx "+
            "set chronic = " + sChronic  +
            " where (trim(lower(cdesc)), trim(cicd9)) = "+
            " ('"+dx.description.Trim().ToLower()+"','"+dx.icd9.Trim() +"');";

 using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(UpdateCmd, conn))
            {
               command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("value1", NpgsqlDbType.Text));

               command.Parameters[0].Value = "Big Tom's Dog";

             ....... ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ...................
```

How is this done?  Any help is most appreciated.

TIA

Comment: See their [documentation](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual) under "Prepared statements". Manually composing query strings is extremely error prone, so avoid inserting data using string concatenation whenever possible. Also try and bump your Postgres version, 9.4 adds a lot of new features that are worth having.

Comment: @tadman I still don't get how to work with the single quote when it is part of the record, or does it not matter? Thanks.

Comment: Being concerned about quotes is a sign you're not escaping properly. The best way to do this is **prepared statements** where the database driver handles escaping for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @tadman says, you should never use string concatenation to compose your query - that is the source of SQL injection. However, there's no need to prepare your statement. Use parameter placeholders in your query, something like the following should work:

```
string UpdateCmd = "update dx set chronic = @p1 where (trim(lower(cdesc)), trim(cicd9)) = (@p2);";

using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(UpdateCmd, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "chronic");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", "value");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```